# Web application user defined content with database content inserted

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have been attempting to research the best way to do the following:

Save a user-defined text based expression to a database which outlines content to be displayed on a page.

example: "The employment status of this person is a [employment] employee, [hours] hrs a week."

Where [employment], [hours] correspond to a key/value in a database

example:

```
TABLE
ID    KEY             VALUE
1     employment      casual
1     hours           10
2     employment      parttime
2     hours           25
```

At runtime a page where this user-defined expression would be used for display has access to a persons id and would need to collect the relevant details from the database, parse and replace the [employment], [hours] placeholders with the retrieved data.

example: "The employment status of this person is a casual employee, 10 hrs a week.

The solution I am looking for needs to be dynamic enough to handle a user entering any static text in and around any number of placeholders.

---

**EDIT** to clarify my meaning:

There will be a settings area where the user can enter the expression they want
displayed on the screen, which could be any text containing any 'key' values from
the database. Different users will see their own defined expression displayed.

another example: "The employee works [hours] hrs, [employment]"

would display as: "The employee works 10 hrs, casual"

---

I'm either not doing very well with my searching or just not understanding the results very well. I have found a lot of information regarding CustomExpressionBuilder, Lambda expressions, Expression trees, etc. and I am getting confused whether any of these are the right track for what I need to do. Perhaps I'm just not there yet on my understanding being new to this!

If I can get this working I would also love to be able to add some simple ternary type functionality and/or mathematical functionality.  It seems like there is library called [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) that would make this quite simple, but I could not see an example of the text replacement requirement that I initially need, or immediately see a way to tweak it to work.

Thanks for any advice, and I am more than happy to research further but need a little push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it's a bit vague as to how far you've gotten with this problem, ie if you are already able to retrieve all of the values from the database or not.

If you are simply trying to build a string expression as you mentioned above, once you have the values above, I would probably use either String.Format or perhaps a string builder.

For example, if we presume that you have the values out of the database and they are contained within properties on a Person class (just as an example), you could write something to the effect of:

```
var message = String.Format("The employment status of this person is a {0} employee, {1} hrs a week.", person.Employment, person.Hours);
```

Like I said, it's a bit vague from your question exactly where your issue is, but if you're just looking to build that one particular expression once you have the values, the above would work. You can replace the person.Employment and person.Hours arguments with the appropriate values once you have those out of the database.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'm fine with getting the details out of the database and passing them into a string.format in this way.  My problem is with making it dynamic.  User must be able to customize the string from my example to whatever they want eg."The person works [hours] hrs, [employment]" or "The person is living at [housing]".  I'll try an edit to clarify.  Thanks again.

Comment: With that in mind, you could pass the string that the user has created as the first parameter in the String.Format method. Granted, they will have to add the bracketed arguments within the string that they pass in, but that could be handled within whatever area they create that string.